# Trouble in compiling classes with dependency

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, java-server, java-12

Under the root directory, there are two directories named src and classes.

I have two java files named Master and Slave.

Slave file is under the directory `src/com/example/web` and compiled master file is under the directory `classes/com/example/model`.

I have compiled the master class is used.
In `Slave.java`,  Master class is used with the help of

```
import com.example.model.Master
```

But while compiling in the root directory using

```
javac -classpath classes -d classes src\com\example\web\Slave.java
```

the following error is thrown:

> package com.example.model does not exist

Answer (score 0):

if you know the Hierarchy of dependeny , you should build all classes based on dependency.
in this case yous should execute this commands sequential :

first

```
javac -classpath classes -d classes src\com\example\model\Master
```

then

```
javac -classpath classes -d classes src\com\example\web\Slave.java
```

if you have more than a class in packages you can build all with wild cards. for example:

```
javac -classpath classes -d classes src\com\example\model\*.java
```

Comment: Sorry I have not mentioned in the question but I compiled the master first and then I compiled the slave but it didn't worked.